SwiftPM executable target - assets work from Xcode but not the command-line
Context
Consider a simple Swift Package with a MyLibrary and MyExecutable target.
The aim is for MyExecutable to use MyLibrary (which has an image).
The MyLibrary target has 2 files, a Resources/Assets.xcassets catalog (with 1 image named "Test") and an Images.swift file like so:
private extension NSImage {
    static let test = Bundle.module.image(forResource: "Test")
}

public struct Images {
    public static func printTestExists() {
        print("Exists: \(NSImage.test != nil)")
    }
}

Please note in particular the use of Bundle.module here. The MyExecutable consists of merely a main.swift file that imports MyLibrary and runs:
Images.printTestExists()

Issue
When running the MyExecutable scheme in Xcode, it works as expected printing:
Exists: true

However, when running the executable from the command line:
swift run -c release MyExecutable

it crashes with the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSBundle imageForResource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Question
Why do assets seem not to work from the command-line? I'm only executing the swift run command so the executable file should have access to the library bundle, right?
Package.swift
The assets are processed as a resource as you would expect
let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
        .executable(name: "MyExecutable", targets: ["MyExecutable"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLibrary", resources: [.process("Resources")] ),
        .executableTarget(name: "MyExecutable", dependencies: ["MyLibrary"])
    ]
)

Aside
Using the following SwiftUI code from the command-line would similarly not show an image but works when run from Xcode:
Image("Test", bundle: .module)

Attachments

References
I found a similar issue on Swift forums

To only half answer my own question, I believe the issue is just that swift run does not support assets. Hopefully, a future answer shows us how to make it work.
I managed to workaround the issue using the xcodebuild command instead
# Set this to what you want (this is inside the SwiftPM `.build` directory)
derivedDataPath=".build/xcode-derived-data"
    
xcodebuild build \
    -configuration release \
    -scheme MyExecutable \
    -sdk macosx \
    -destination 'platform=macOS' \
    -derivedDataPath "$derivedDataPath"
   
$derivedDataPath/Build/Products/release/MyExecutable

To see other destinations run
xcodebuild -showdestinations -scheme MyExecutable

It does not require making an .xcodeproj file which is nice, so we can stay in the realm of SwiftPM. Still, swift run would be preferable, but I hope this helps in the interim.
